# is there any formula to get travel time between two locations or from distance in flutter without using google maps

Tags: flutter, travel-time

I have two locations and I have the formula to get the distance between them but I want to calculate the travel time between them without using google maps or any API calling. Is there any formula to do that in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real travel time depends on a lot of factors, for example the road you take or the speed limit.

Whitout some complex elaboration, which are usually perfomed by a backend, I don't think it is possible to calculate it.

Anyway, since you have got the distance, you could simply estimate it by giving a supposed speed and then using basic physics formulas.

time = distance / speed.

Comment: thank you, i tried that but it sometimes it gives different values from google api, with big different values

Comment: As I said, for real travel time, you need to use complex algorithm (which takes care of a lot of different parameters) which are usually implemented in some complex backend which are accessible by API. This is just a physics formula, I think it's obvious that the results don't match.

Comment: If you think it helped, please consider upvoting. Thanks.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I just thought if there was a river between the two locations, the calculated driving time would be very different.

Comment: If you know the location of some intermediate points, like a bridge, you could iterate the process and get a more precise result

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot find the travel distance between two locations without using the Google API.**
*However you can get the air distance in meters using this formula in flutter.*

```
double calculateDistance(
      double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    var temp = 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
    return (temp * 1000);
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much, i did that but do you know is the result in km or meter ? , and it sometimes gives different values fro google api, do you know any other accurate formula ?

Comment: yes, its results in meters not in Km. Moreover, the result may vary a little bit because the latitude and longitude may vary for the same place. because the mobile caches different lat, long even for the same place.